# how to converts absolute 3d coordinates to pov coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

Given the coordinates of the planets in spaces, how can I convert them into a point-of-view coordinates, i.e. a person standing on Earth looking at the sky?

I am trying to write a software to simulate the motion of the planets from the view point of a person in a certain latitude/longitude on Earth when he looks at the sky.

Comment: You have to specify how the "coordinates in space" are given.

Comment: saulspatz, let's assume the center of the Sun is the origin (0,0,0).

Comment: And while you're at it, you might want to say how you'd like the "viewer coordinates" specified, too: On some image plane for an imaginary pinhole camera? In "degrees from zenith / degrees from heading" coordinates (where "heading" is the direction your toes are pointing as you stand on the earth)? Or something else?

Comment: OK. The coordinate system has the sun as its origin. Is the plane of the ecliptic the $xy$-plane? Or are you going to use the polar axis of the earth as the $y$- (or perhaps $z$-) direction to make conversion from lat/lon coords of the viewer easier?

Comment: John Hughes, whatever makes the solution/derivation easier. But, I prefer to have the plane of the elliptic to be the xy-plane

Comment: the viewer or camera coordinates are supposed to be 3d, exactly as you would see them when looking at the sky. The user should be able to drag the screen (change the orientation and position of the camera) to see different views on the sky.